# What is the correct way to compute mean PSNR among a dataset?

Tags: image-processing

I am working on a image quality assessment tasks and am wondering can we compute the average among a dataset? If we can, what is the correct way to compute it?  In my analysis, the ***method2*** should be the correcte way, but I don't know whether this analysis is correct or is there any other method to compute PSNR among a dataset.
[My analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJSXO.png)

Comment: You could also try on https://stats.stackexchange.com/